# Mongodb aggregation pipeline to get subdocument object as string

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB collection containing documents like these:

```
   {
    "id": "62cd5de762c595905e37821b",
    "letterNo": "122233",
    "letterDate": "2023-03-01",
    "metaData": {
      "name": "test",
      "family ": "test"
     }
  },
   {
    "id": "62cd5de762c595905e37821a",
    "letterNo": "122233",
    "letterDate": "2023-03-01",
    "metaData": {
      "type": "xxxx",
      "where": "test"
     }
  }
```

I want to $group in metaData field as metaData_string, that every shema change to string live this:

```
   {
    "id": "62cd5de762c595905e37821a",
    "letterNo": "122233",
    "letterDate": "1400-03-01",
    "metaData_string":"{\n'name': 'test',\n'family ': 'test'\n}"
  },
  {
    "id": "62cd5de762c595905e37821a",
    "letterNo": "122233",
    "letterDate": "1400-03-01",
    "metaData_string":"{\n'type': 'xxxxx',\n'where': 'test'\n}"
  }
```

Is it possible using the Aggregation Framework only? I haven't seen reference to subdocuments in the aggregation framework documentation, so I think it's not...

Thx you all.

Comment: Why do you want to convert it to `string` to use in `$group`?

Comment: I need to insert result in this structure in an RDBMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$function`, if it's a one-time operation, but you'll need to enable server-side javascript. Like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "metaData": {
        "$function": {
          "body": "function(obj) { return JSON.stringify(obj)}",
          "args": [
            "$$ROOT.metaData"
          ],
          "lang": "js"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground link.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DNu0UDmfzvC)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the above answer due to *security vulnerability such as JS injection* I recommend using `$map, $reduce` operator to get the string result and concat them together, below is the solution I come up with that also handles the nested list of objects:

```
 { $project: {
   "metaData": {
     $map: {
       input: {
         $objectToArray: "$metaData"  // $map only get the array to we are converting the object to array and input it in metaData
       },
       as: "metaData",
       in: {
         $cond: {
           if: {
             $isArray: "$$metaData.v"   // check the if value of our metadata is is array if yes check the the null value first   and use $reduce to deconstruct the array in single value
           },
           then: {
             "customer": {
               $reduce: {
                 input: {
                   $ifNull: [
                     "$$metaData.v",
                     []
                   ]
                 },
                 initialValue: "",
                 in: {
                   $map: {
                     input: {
                       $objectToArray: "$$this"  // as we have  inner array use another map to get the objects value  and use $toString to convert the values to string
                     },
                     as: "cdata",
                     in: {
                       $concat: [
                         {
                           $toString: "$$cdata.k"
                         },
                         "\":\"",
                         {
                           $toString: "$$cdata.v"
                         }
                       ]
                     }
                   }
                 }
               }
             },
             
           },
           else: {      // this part  returns the non-array object values
             $concat: [
               "{ \"",
               "$$metaData.k",
               "\": \"",
               "$$metaData.v",
               "\" }"
             ]
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

[Playground_Link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/A5Ut-hdsAUe)

Answer (score 0):

If server side execution of JavaScript is enabled you can use JSON.stringify inside $function operator but if it's not enabled (for example in Atlas Data Federation) you can this function to generate the required mongodb pipeline operators to stringify the object.

```
function toJSON(input){
  function concatPrimitive(input) {
    let query = { $cond: [
            {
              $in: [ {$type: input}, ["double", "bool", "long", "int", "null"]]
            },
            {
              $convert : {input: input, to: "string", onError: "Error", onNull: "null"}
            },
            {
              "$concat": [ "\"", {$convert : {input: input, to: "string", onError: "Error"}}, "\""]
            }
          ]
        }
    return query;
  }
  
  function concatArray(input, level, maxLevel){
    level = level + 1;
    if (level >= maxLevel) return concatPrimitive(input);
    let query = {$concat: ["[",
    {  
      $rtrim: {
        input: {
          $reduce: {
            input: input,
            initialValue: "",
            in: {
              $cond: {
                if: {$isArray: "$$this"}, 
                then: { 
                  $concat: [ "$$value", concatArray("$$this", level, maxLevel), ","]
                },
                else: { 
                  $cond: { if: {$eq: [{ $type: "$$this" }, "object"] },
                    then: { $concat: [ "$$value", concatObject("$$this", level, maxLevel), ","]}, 
                    else: { $concat: [ "$$value", concatPrimitive("$$this"), ","]}
                  }
                }
              }
            }  
          }
        }, 
        chars: ","
      }
    }
    ,"]"]} 
    return query;
  }
  
  function concatObject(input, level, maxLevel){
    level = level + 1;
    if (level >= maxLevel) return concatPrimitive(input);
    let query = {$concat: ["{",
    {  
      $rtrim: {
        input: {
          $reduce: {
          input: {"$objectToArray": input},
          initialValue: "",
          in: {
            $cond: {
              if: {$isArray: "$$this.v"}, 
              then: { 
                $concat: [ "$$value", "\"", "$$this.k", "\":", concatArray("$$this.v", level, maxLevel), ","]
              },
              else: { 
                $cond: {
                  if: { $eq: [{ $type: "$$this.v" }, "object"] },
                  then: { $concat: [ "$$value", "\"", "$$this.k", "\":", concatObject("$$this.v", level, maxLevel), ","]}, 
                  else: { $concat: [ "$$value", "\"", "$$this.k", "\":", concatPrimitive("$$this.v"), ","]}
                }
              }
            }
          }  
        }
        }, 
        chars: ","
      }
    }
    ,"}"]} 
    return query;
  }
  let level = 0;
  let maxLevel = 5;
  return {      
        $concat: [
          {
            $cond: { if: {$isArray: input},
              then: concatArray(input, level, maxLevel),
              else: {
                $cond: { if: {$eq: [{ $type: input}, "object"]},
                  then: concatObject(input, level, maxLevel),
                  else: concatPrimitive(input)
                }
              }
            }
          },
        ]
  }
}

db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "metaData_string": toJSON("$metaData")
    }
  }
])
```

You can change maxLevel if your objects are bigger.